# JNI change C to C++

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a simple piece of code that i want to use in my java (android) application:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring 
Java_com_example_ndk_MainActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

If i use C and call this file *.c - everything is ok, but i want this code on C++, i rename this file to *.cpp (and change Android.mk). Everything is compiled but when i try to use this function in the way i've used it in C, i have a error.

*Also i modify body of the func:

```
    return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from JNI !");
```

Try to use this:

```
public native String stringFromJNI();

static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
}
```

And got such an error:

```
09-10 17:55:46.410: W/dalvikvm(6339): No implementation found for native Lcom/example/ndk/MainActivity;.stringFromJNI ()Ljava/lang/String;


09-10 17:55:46.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6339): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: stringFromJNI
09-10 17:55:46.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at com.example.ndk.MainActivity.stringFromJNI(Native Method)
09-10 17:55:46.410: E/AndroidRuntime(6339):     at com.example.ndk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
```

I can't understand why the same code run in C and fail (runtime) in C++.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To allow for overloading of functions, C++ uses something called *name mangling*. This means that function names are not the same in C++ as in plain C.

To inhibit this name mangling, you have to declare functions as `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" jstring 
Java_com_example_ndk_MainActivity_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                 jobject thiz)
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI !");
}
```

Comment: Maybe i don't explain my problem very good: the error occur when i use C++, i don't want to run C from C++, i only want to run C++ code (as i said i've modified code "return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from JNI !");") but there is a error on runtime

Comment: @dilix The function is still C++, it's just the function name that will not be "mangled" so it will be callable from C code. See e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) for a description on name mangling.

Comment: The main idea is only to run c++ code without c. Now i can run *.c code but there is a described error when i try to start code from *.cpp (without c code)

Comment: @dilix Like I said, the code _is_ C++, it's just _the function name_ that is not C++ specific. The actual code inside the function is 100% C++. Read the Wikipedia article I linked to in my previous comment! Without that `extern "C"` declaration the JVM can't call your _C++_ function.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll read this articles, your code perfectly fits me

Answer (score 2):

To use [C calling conventions in C++ code](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/c-calls-cpp.html), surround your functions with:

```c++
extern "C" 
{
    /* your C API */
}
```

Comment: Maybe i don't explain my problem very good: the error occur when i use C++, i don't want to run C from C++, i only want to run C++ code (as i said i've modified code "return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from JNI !");") but there is a error on runtime